# How to tell the margin of the template I downloaded?

Tags: margins

I downloaded a thesis template from this link on overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-and-dissertation-latex-templates-for-harvard-princeton-and-new-york-university-nyu/wkzvtymyxqvv#.WFFqWaIrJPU. It's from Harvard.

And I just wonder how/where can I tell what margin is in this template? I just want to make sure that it fits my school requirement.

Comment: old school solution: print a page and use the archaic tool of a ruler.

Comment: The .cls has a line `\RequirePackage[width=5.75in, letterpaper]{geometry}`.  Compile your document and open `<docname>.log` in your editor and look for `*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:`

Comment: The interesting part from `Dissertate.cls` is  `\RequirePackage[width=5.75in, letterpaper]{geometry}`

Comment: so does the 5.75in represent the width of the text line in this template? the total width of the letter paper is 11in, so does it mean the margin is (11-5.75)in? well, that doesn't seem right...or is the width 5.75in the margin actually?

Comment: @Yvonne The 5.75 in is the textwidth, the paperwidth is 8.5in, this means that right and left margin are together 2.75in.

Comment: I see. So if I change the width parameter here, I can set a new margin for my document, is it right?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the package `layout`.

Create a MWE, using your newly downloaded Harvard class, insert `\usepackage{layout}` in the preamble and finally use the command `\layout` in your document.

See the documentation of the package.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{layout}
\begin{document}
\layout
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you tell me where I should use the command \layout to set margin for all the main text in this thesis template? My school asks for a margin of 1 inch or 1 ½ inches all around, so how should I use this commend then?

Comment: Edited my answer and added an MWE.

Comment: my apology, i didn't make my question clear. So I mean where to define the margin number in \layout command?

Comment: @Yvonne `\geometry{margin=1in, right=1.5in, bottom=1.5in}` before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @Yvonne If you don't have to use that template, don't use it. It is not of the best quality.

Comment: @Yvonne, the `\layout` command will produce an image, which represents the header, text-area and footer of your document.  You can use it with nearly every document class.  It is more a tool to check, that all your dimensions you defined, are working properly.  If you want/have to change the layout of a given class, e. g. scrreprt, you can use packages like geometry.  See the documentation of http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry  As Johannes said, try to avoid the Harvard class.  Choose KOMA-Script. :-)

Comment: I see. That makes a lot sense. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Your downloaded `dissertate.cls`.

```
\setlength\paperheight {11in}

\setlength\paperwidth  {8.5in}
```

[image]

You can find this on dissertate.cls file. At line number 68.

Comment: Can you expand your answer? Right now, it seems to be more of an out of context comment.